# Assign 1 randomly value to the dataframe rows - Help needed

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, numpy

I want to randomly assign 1 value to the IsShade column (output) such that value 1 can be assigned only D times (see column Shading for ex 2 times or 5 times or 3 times) and have to iterate it for E times (Total column for ex 6 times or 8 times or 15 times)

There are 1 million rows of dataset and attached is sample input and image.

So, explaining my input dataset:
This is for Solar Panel prediction using ML. Series X Parallel X Shading means that there will be 3 solar panel connected in series, 2 solar panel connected in parallel and out of 6 (3 X 2) solar panels, 2 of them are shaded (means the solar panels are covered with some kind of shading)

So, here Cell column is just the representation of how many solar panels are there for each group like 3 X 2 then another is also 3 X 2 but it is for different locations and with different shading values.

So, output of IsShade column should come in the range of 1 to (3 X 2) which is 6 rows, any random X rows (shading column value) should be marked as 1 and remaining as 0 values for each group. It should same happened for another 5-11 rows again but with different random location rows. I hope you get a gist of it. Sorry about not explaining clear.

Input:

In[1]:

```
Series Parallel  Shading Total  Cell 
3         2        2      6     1         
3         2        2      6     2        
3         2        2      6     3        
3         2        2      6     4        
3         2        2      6     5        
3         2        2      6     6        
3         2        2      6     1        
3         2        2      6     2        
3         2        2      6     3        
3         2        2      6     4        
3         2        2      6     5        
3         2        2      6     6
```

If you can help me in how to achieve or python code that will be helpful. Thank you and appreciate it.

Example Expected Output:

Out[1]:

```
Series Parallel  Shading Total  Cell  IsShade 
3         2        2      6     1        0 
3         2        2      6     2        0
3         2        2      6     3        1
3         2        2      6     4        0
3         2        2      6     5        0
3         2        2      6     6        1
3         2        2      6     1        0 
3         2        2      6     2        0
3         2        2      6     3        0
3         2        2      6     4        1
3         2        2      6     5        1
3         2        2      6     6        0
```

Comment: @jezrael, sorry updated the post. Thanks for pointing out. Please can you assist me

Comment: Thanks, each group is defined by `Series` column?

Comment: Yes, each group out put of IsShade should come according to the Series columne
For example, for 0-5 rows, Series is 3 and shading is 2, so output should come 2 times 1 value in IsShade column
For example, 6-13 rows, Series is 4 and shading is 5, so there should 5 random 1 values assign in the IsShade column only for that group series.

Comment: Super, last question - are always values in `Shading` column less like length of group like in sample data?

Comment: Value of Shading will be less than or equal to (Series*Parallel) value 
For 1st example, it can be 6 value in Shading or 5 or less than.

Comment: Yes, and we need output of IsShade for each group like from 1 to 6 then 1 to 8 then 1 to 15 even though Series value is same

Comment: We need to create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use counter in `Cell` column and add `1` values if less or equal like `Shading` column in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then use [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) per groups specified by consecutive values of `Series` column:

```
g = df['Cell'].eq(1).cumsum()

df['IsShade'] = np.where(df['Cell'].le(df['Shading']), 1, 0)
df['IsShade'] = df.groupby(g)['IsShade'].transform(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))

print (df)
    Series  Parallel  Shading  Total  Cell  IsShade
0        3         2        2      6     1        0
1        3         2        2      6     2        1
2        3         2        2      6     3        0
3        3         2        2      6     4        1
4        3         2        2      6     5        0
5        3         2        2      6     6        0
6        3         2        2      6     1        0
7        3         2        2      6     2        0
8        3         2        2      6     3        1
9        3         2        2      6     4        0
10       3         2        2      6     5        0
11       3         2        2      6     6        1
```

Another idea with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    size = x.iat[0]
    total = len(x) 
    a = np.concatenate([np.ones(size, dtype=int), np.zeros(total - size, dtype=int)])
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    return a

g = df['Cell'].eq(1).cumsum()

df['IsShade'] = df.groupby(g)['Shading'].transform(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it is giving error. Error is IsShade column is taking whole combine and not with each series.

Comment: Alright, so the error is:- I'm getting IsShade output for all the groups combine. Let say for 1-6 rows, Shading value is 2 then IsShade column should consist of only 2 rows with 1 value rest 4 rows with 0 value. Now again after7-12 rows, we have all Series, Parallel, Shading SAME value, then with your solution output is coming 0 only (ideally it should come any 2 rows as 1 value and rest 4 rows as 0 value? But now in overall IsShading column I am getting only 2 rows with 1 value

Comment: it's still not coming each group. I have updated Input column with the values where I am getting. Can you try to see the example in the question (updated new value for 0-5 rows and 6-11 rows with same value

Comment: Have updated the post with all details. Sorry for not explaining clear. Would like to connect on LinkedIn and discuss - https://www.linkedin.com/in/kevalcshah0510/

Comment: sorry for mis confusion. Cell data is already counted as in the Input dataset. Only IsShade column needs to be added with the logic. Thanks

Comment: @KevalShah - Super, so for start of each group is `cell=1` ? If yes, edited answer should working well.

Comment: thank you so much for all the help, I couldn't appreciate your time and effort. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @KevalShah - thank you for patience too ;)  You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I'm facing a problem with confusion matrix. Can you have a look and assist me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617170/confusion-matrix-for-10-cross-fold-how-to-do-it-pandas-dataframe-df