# Confusion Matrix for 10 cross fold - How to do it pandas dataframe df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm trying to get 10 fold confusion matrix for any models (Random forest, Decision tree, Naive Bayes. etc)
I can able to get each confusion matrix normally if I run for normal model as below shown:

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
    
    # implementing train-test-split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.34, random_state=66)
    
    # random forest model creation
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=39, max_depth=4)
    rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)
    # predictions
    rfc_predict = rfc.predict(X_test)
    
    print("=== Confusion Matrix ===")
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, rfc_predict))
    print('\n')
    print("=== Classification Report ===")
    print(classification_report(y_test, rfc_predict))
```

Out[1]:

```
    === Confusion Matrix ===
    [[16243  1011]
     [  827 16457]]
    
    
    === Classification Report ===
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support
    
               0       0.95      0.94      0.95     17254
               1       0.94      0.95      0.95     17284
    
        accuracy                           0.95     34538
       macro avg       0.95      0.95      0.95     34538
    weighted avg       0.95      0.95      0.95     34538
```

But, now I want to get **confusion matrix for 10 cv fold**. How should I approach or do it. I tried this but not working.

```
    # from sklearn import cross_validation
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)
    
    conf_matrix_list_of_arrays = []
    kf = cross_validate(rfc, X, y, cv=kfold)
    print(kf)
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
    
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    
        rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
        conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, rfc.predict(X_test))
        conf_matrix_list_of_arrays.append(conf_matrix)
```

Dataset consists of this dataframe dp

```
Temperature Series  Parallel    Shading Number of cells Voltage(V)  Current(I)  I/V     Solar Panel Cell Shade Percentage   IsShade
30          10      1           2       10              1.11        2.19        1.97    1985        1   20.0                1
27          5       2          10       10              2.33        4.16        1.79    1517        3   100.0   1
30  5   2   7   10  2.01    4.34    2.16    3532    1   70.0    1
40  2   4   3   8   1.13    -20.87  -18.47  6180    1   37.5    1
45  5   2   4   10  1.13    6.52    5.77    8812    3   40.0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [help page for cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) it doesn't return the indexes used for cross-validation. You need to access the indices from the (Stratified)KFold, using an example dataset:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.34, random_state=66)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=111,shuffle=True)
skf.split(X_train,y_train)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=39, max_depth=4)
y_pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, X_train, y_train, cv=skf)
```

We apply `cross_val_predict` to get all the predictions:

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, X, y, cv=skf)
```

Then use the indices to split this y_pred to each confusion matrix:

```
mats = []
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X_train,y_train):
    mats.append(confusion_matrix(y_train[test_index],y_pred[test_index]))
```

Looks like this:

```
mats[:3]

[array([[13,  2],
        [ 0, 23]]),
 array([[14,  1],
        [ 1, 22]]),
 array([[14,  1],
        [ 0, 23]])]
```

Check that the addition of the matrices list and total sum is the same:

```
np.add.reduce(mats)

array([[130,  14],
       [  6, 225]])

confusion_matrix(y_train,y_pred)

array([[130,  14],
       [  6, 225]])
```

Comment: Giving this error - ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: sorry what is giving you an error? Running the code above on your dataset or running the above code? I noticed a typo in my code above and corrected, so if you run that above it should work

Comment: Meaning there is something different about your data

Comment: Giving error on this line - mats.append(confusion_matrix(y_train[test_index],y_pred[test_index])) ..........I think it is because I have dataset of 2d as I have mentioned in the last of the question top. Do you mind if we can connect on LinkedIn - https://www.linkedin.com/in/kevalcshah0510/

Comment: sorry @KevalShah seems like no one will be able to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem here stands in the incorrect unpacking of `kf`. Indeed, `cross_validate()` returns a dictionary of arrays with test_scores and fit/score times by default.

You can leverage instead on `split()` method of your `Kfold` instance, that helps you generating indices to split data into training and test(validation) set. Therefore, by changing into

`for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(X_train, y_train):`

you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: it is giving error - AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-08b16887d48d> in <module>
      8 print(kf)
      9 #for train_index, test_index in kf:
---> 10 for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train, y_train):
     11 
     12     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You should call split() on kfold and not on kf. Indeed, the KFold class implements method split().

Comment: Moreover, another feasible way could be using `cross_val_predict()` to obtain the predictions made on each test fold and then calling `confusion_matrix()` on the obtained predictions, like this: `y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, X_train, y_train, cv=10)`
`confusion_matrix(y_train,  y_train_pred)`
However, I haven't reported it in the answer because from what I could understand you wanted to obtain one confusion matrix per cv fold, while in this way `y_train_pred` would be a 1d array due to a specificity of `cross_val_predict`.

Comment: ---> 12     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]  ......................KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 6705,  6706,  6707,  6708,  6709,  6710,  6711,  6712,  6713,\n             6714,\n            ...\n            67032, 67033, 67034, 67035, 67036, 67037, 67038, 67039, 67040,\n            67041],\n           dtype='int64', length=60337)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: I guess the point then is that X is still a DataFrame for you and you should access it using `iloc()`.

Comment: Like this, `X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]`. Anyway, this really depends on the treatment you applied to your data. 
Moreover, if you already created `X_train` at the very beginning of your code, my idea is that you should better write `X_train, X_test = X_train.iloc[train_index], X_train.iloc[test_index]` because in cross validation the idea is to take the training set and split it into a smaller training set and a validation set.